# how to do memory management in iOS.Xamarin

Tags: uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I have 3 screens.
1)start screen where i have a button on tap of which i land to 2nd screen.
2)I have a table view with images and labels on tap of row i land to next page
3)Screen with images.
I have the DataSource and the list of images and list of text
In my table view datasource class in getcell method i am getting cell.ImageView=null but i am able to show the images.How to solve this problem of imageview as null.The code is as follows:

```
public override UITableViewCell(UITableView tableview,NSIndexPath indexpath)
{
var cell= (Mytablecellclassname)tableview.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
if(cell==null)
{
cell=new Mytablecellclassname((NSString)cellIdentifier);
}
cell.ImageView.Image=tableItems[indexpath.row];
}
```

where tableItems is list of UIImages. 
How to do memory management?I am using weak reference and still i am not able   to do since i am new to this.

Comment: How is the class Mytablecellclassname defined?

Comment: It inherits UItableviewcell and icell and i have implemented icell interface i.e clean cell where i am checking my image view if it is not null i am making it null.

Comment: please share the code for Mytablecellclassname. You stated you make the imageview null ? Then of course it is null which is your problem right?